# Replace NA with group value in loop across multiple columns

Tags: r, loops, replace

I want to replace NA with group value (not mean or median, since some columns are character or factor) and I want to do this for a list of columns using the same group for all.

Sample data:

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3)
V1 <- c(NA,"HEJ",NA,"BOS","BOS",NA,"IB","IB")
V2 <- c(700,700,NA,3000,NA,NA,NA,1000)
V3 <- c(NA,NA,3,1,1,1,2,NA)
V4 <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"LA",NA,"FE")
mydf <- data.frame(ID,V1,V2,V3,V4)

> mydf
  ID   V1   V2 V3   V4
1  1 <NA>  700 NA <NA>
2  1  HEJ  700 NA <NA>
3  1 <NA>   NA  3 <NA>
4  2  BOS 3000  1 <NA>
5  2  BOS   NA  1 <NA>
6  2 <NA>   NA  1   LA
7  3   IB   NA  2 <NA>
8  3   IB 1000 NA   FE
```

So I know if I only wanted to do this for one column I would:

```
setDT(mydf)[, V1:= 
                V1[!is.na(V1)][1L],
                by = ID]
```

And then get:

```
> mydf
   ID  V1   V2 V3   V4
1:  1 HEJ  700 NA <NA>
2:  1 HEJ  700 NA <NA>
3:  1 HEJ   NA  3 <NA>
4:  2 BOS 3000  1 <NA>
5:  2 BOS   NA  1 <NA>
6:  2 BOS   NA  1   LA
7:  3  IB   NA  2 <NA>
8:  3  IB 1000 NA   FE
```

But I have a lot of columns, so I need to put it in a loop of some kind.

Desired output:

```
> mydf
   ID  V1   V2 V3   V4
1:  1 HEJ  700  3 <NA>
2:  1 HEJ  700  3 <NA>
3:  1 HEJ  700  3 <NA>
4:  2 BOS 3000  1   LA
5:  2 BOS 3000  1   LA
6:  2 BOS 3000  1   LA
7:  3  IB 1000  2   FE
8:  3  IB 1000  2   FE
```

And this is what I've tried without luck:

```
names <- colnames(mydf[,-c(1)])

for(j in seq_along(nm1)){

   set(mydf,
       i = which(is.na(mydf[[names[j]]])),
       j = names[j],
       value = mydf[[names[j]]][is.na(mydf[[names[j]]])])
}
```

And I also tried this:

```
mydf[,-c(1] <- lapply(mydf, function(x) 
  replace(x, is.na(x), x[!is.na(x)]))

> mydf
  ID V1  V2   V3 V4
1  1  1 HEJ  700  3
2  1  1 HEJ  700  1
3  1  1 BOS  700  3
4  2  2 BOS 3000  1
5  2  2 BOS  700  1
6  2  2 BOS 3000  1
7  3  3  IB 1000  2
8  3  3  IB 1000  1
```

I'm sorry if I'm asking a question that's already out there but I wasn't able to find it. I hope somebody can help me cleaning up my messy data :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `dplyr` and `tidyr` possibilty could be:

```
mydf %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 fill(-ID, .direction = "downup")

     ID V1       V2    V3 V4   
  <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>
1     1 HEJ     700     3 <NA> 
2     1 HEJ     700     3 <NA> 
3     1 HEJ     700     3 <NA> 
4     2 BOS    3000     1 LA   
5     2 BOS    3000     1 LA   
6     2 BOS    3000     1 LA   
7     3 IB     1000     2 FE   
8     3 IB     1000     2 FE
```

Comment: Edit: asked if it works if the bottom value is NA, but I can see my sample data already has a column case like that (V3)

Comment: Can you please elaborate this question? I'm not sure that I understand :)

Comment: It doesn't work on my sample data..I get the error "Error in match.arg(.direction) : 'arg' should be one of “down”, “up”"

Comment: tried with both up and down, and neither provides the desired output

Comment: This argument is relatively new, try update to the newest version of `tidyr`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `.SDcols` to apply the function to multiple columns.

```
library(data.table)

cols <- names(mydf[-1])
setDT(mydf)

mydf[, (cols):= lapply(.SD, function(x) 
         replace(x, is.na(x), x[!is.na(x)][1])),.SDcols = cols, by = ID]
mydf

#   ID  V1   V2 V3   V4
#1:  1 HEJ  700  3 <NA>
#2:  1 HEJ  700  3 <NA>
#3:  1 HEJ  700  3 <NA>
#4:  2 BOS 3000  1   LA
#5:  2 BOS 3000  1   LA
#6:  2 BOS 3000  1   LA
#7:  3  IB 1000  2   FE
#8:  3  IB 1000  2   FE
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but it overwrites for those columns without NA in them and I don't want that, so I think for my case the fill works better. Thanks though. It was something like this I was looking for.

Comment: @LouiseSørensen Updated the answer to replace only `NA` values.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `na.locf` from `zoo`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, na.locf(.SD), by = ID, .SDcols = V2:V4]
```